# PHP Yii : when enter arabic text to username field in login show error CDbException

Tags: php, yii

i write UserIdentity method authenticate() under script:

```
$user =  UserAccounts::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));

    if($user === null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif($user->password!==$this->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;

    return !$this->errorCode;
```

but exist one warning problem : when i type arabic to text box username field shows that Error :

for example username = 'شسیششب'; or any text arabic

**CDbCommand**
failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `useraccounts` `t` WHERE `t`.`username`=:yp0 
LIMIT 1

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that encoding and collation of your `useraccounts` table are not suitable for comparison with [UTF-8](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#charset-detail) input from your YII application. Try to change your table's character set to `utf8` and collation `utf8_general_ci` like [it shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373180/506695):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```